# Woocommerce Adding price amount class ("woocommerce-Price-amount amount) to return $price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I am building a measurement Store with Woo and need some special Outputs for Pricing I am not able to fix.

The Price Output needs to be:

Price per Package 
and the
Price per Unit
so I need to add the class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" for Display

1) I had used this Snippet to Display the Unit of Package Price:

```html
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $price .= ' per package';
    return $price;
  }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'wb_checkout_review', 10, 3 );
```

2) And tried these to adding the woo Price Amount, resulting into crashing.

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wb_change_product_html' );

function wb_change_product_html( $price ) {
    $price_html = <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> ' . $price . ' per m² </span> ;
    return $price_html;
}
```

I Cant find a $price amount var. or table so I don't know how to fix these. I hope someone is able to help me with these to fix.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It _looks_ like you're just missing the quotes in your `wb_change_product_html` filter: Try adding a `'` before and after the HTML tags.  
If that doesn't help, could you expand a little on what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response,

I want to output the pricing globaly like these eample: 
`
38,37 € per Package 
14,99 € per m²
`
I ll check the html tag thanks.

Comment: Yes the html tag fixing crashing, but doesnt show up the Price per Unit still the Package pricing. But i need to show the output of class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it with adding an shortcode:

```
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $price .= ' per Package';
    echo do_shortcode('[your Shortcode]');

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

Comment: Great to hear you solved the issue. Could you mark your answer as _accepted_ to help others with a similar problem?